# Change loop to Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

One of my function in C# required me to filter some value.So, I try it by using a lot of loop in it. It works but doesn't look like effecient.Any idea on how to convert code below to LinQ?

Any help is appreciated.

```
  var object1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(object1json);
  foreach (var item1 in table1)
            {
                if (item1.Code == InputCode)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < object1.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        tempData temp = new tempData();
                        foreach (var item2 in item1.List) 
                        {
                            if (item2.Code == object1[i])
                            {
                                temp.Code = item2.Code;
                                temp.Description = item2.Description;
                            }
                        }
                        if(temp.Code != null || temp.Description  != null)
                            final.Add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This code won't compile (`object` is a keyword). What is `object`? What is its type? What does the implementation of `.Count()` look like?

Comment: I wouldn't expect converting it to LINQ to result in an improvement in efficiency.

Comment: @Amy The inner `foreach` in the OP's post seems to be performing a logical `JOIN` operation - if that was using a hash-based lookup it would be much faster depending on the size of `object` and `item1.List`.

Comment: @Dai Yes, using a hashmap.  LINQ would be of equivalent efficiency unless the algorithm is altered.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything with `object[i]` - what's the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your code to be more efficient, as pointed out in the comments, converting it to Linq isn't really going to help. It's still the same logic, just written in a different way. If you're going for readability, it can be improved with just a few changes:

```
foreach (var item1 in table1.Where(i => i.Code == InputCode))
{
    foreach (var code in object)
    {
        // This could be SingleOrDefault, I don't know if you have duplicates in the list or not
        var item2 = item1.List.LastOrDefault(i => i.Code == code);

        if(item2 != null)
        {
            final.Add(new tempData
            {
                Code = item2.Code,
                Description = item2.Description,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you convert the whole thing to Linq:

```
var final = table1.Where(i => i.Code == InputCode)
    .SelectMany(item1 => object.Select(code => item1.List.LastOrDefault(i => i.Code == code))
    .Where(item2 => item2 != null)
    .Select(item2 => new tempData
    {
        Code = item2.Code,
        Description = item2.Description,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Personally, I prefer the first option, as it's a bit easier to read.

Comment: Dang! Beat me to it, I was just typing it out in LINQPad. I'd take option 2 for readability, but I also format it differently from yours so it's not as "packed" and busy looking.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you post is sample code instead of actual code otherwise it would be better to avoid keyword like `object` in C#. Anyway,

```
var final = table1.Where(item1 => item1.Code == InputCode)
    .SelectMany(item1 => item1.List)
    .Where(item2 => @object.Contains(item2.Code))
    .Where(temp => temp.Code != null || temp.Description != null)
    .Select(item2 => new tempData()
    {
        Code = item2.Code,
        Description = item2.Description
    });
```

Comment: You can probably merge your two `Where` calls into one.

Comment: `@object.Contains()` is much more readable than the `SelectMany()` expression I wrote, just be aware it may have different behaviour to the original code if there are duplicate entries in `item1.List`